# Redundant MySQL queries in different classes

Tags: php, mysql, redundancy

I'm creating a PHP Webapplication which uses 8 classes (more to come). I realized that all of those classes have pretty much the same functions to access the database: A get_single, a get_list, an insert, update and delete.

Which database table is addressed and which fields are selected is different for every class of course.

For example:

```
function get_single($conn) {

    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT id_person, join_date, img_profile, img_header, firstname, familyname, nationality, mail, password, birthday FROM person WHERE id_person = ?');
    $sql->bind_param('i', $this->id);


    $sql->execute();
    $sql->bind_result($this->id, $this->join_date, $this->profile_img, $this->header_img, $this->firstname, $this->familyname, $this->nationality, $this->mail, $this->password, $this->birthday);

    $sql->fetch();

    return $this;
}
```

I asked myself if I could or should write a single function for all the classes, something like this:

```
function get_single($id, $conn, $query) {

    $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
    $sql->bind_param('i', $id);


    $sql->execute();
    $sql->bind_result(/* ??? */);

    $sql->fetch();

    return /* ??? */ ;
}
```

... and then call

```
$foo = new Foo(array('id' => $bar));
$foo = get_single($foo->id, $conn, $qry_single_foo);
```

This way I could

- store all the SQL queries centrally
- reduce the overall amount of code
- increase readability... maybe?

Or should I have a parent class which those classes inherit from?

Or use a design pattern? Maybe the decorator? (Sorry my knowledge there is quite inexistent)

Now that I realized that it *might* be easier to do it differently I'm a bit overwhelmed by the possibilities.

Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The problem,there is "tight coupling",yor classes are potential "God objects".You may wanna look repository design pattern.. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-repository-design-pattern--net-35804

Comment: Well I'm not completely sure if I use MVC... I have the classes which do all the database connections with querries and everything. I have an index.php where most of the business logic takes place and there I include the different pages, which do all the display work (all the HTML).

Comment: You are kind of right way..But main problem is it's hard to learn-implement OOP with php since it orijins as a scripting language..And OOP is a big world..There maybe some other design patterns etc to solve your problem but your problem refers to Repository design pattern..and It's one of the easiest to understand..

Comment: I am a bit confused (and my code is  a bit wrong). I call the `get_single()`-function like this: `$p->get_single($conn)`. Before I call the function, `$p` is already an object of the desired type, but empty except for an ID. The function just fills it. So why use a factory to create an object that already exists?

Second, I am still not sure how I should generalize the `bind_result()`-function so it is usable by all the classes? Some clases (or database tables) have a "firstname" for exaple, others have a "description" or "filename" that has to be filled with the result...

Thanks so far :)

Comment: Factory Pattern and Repository Pattern are different patterns but mostly used together..Factory Pattern is not about how you "call the object",it's about how you "create the object"..And bind_result() function is a mysql method..So you can use it on your database objects..And repository pattern is for CRUD operations..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web MVC framework or ORM library.

Please check some ORM libraries you can integrate with your application.

**ORM**

- [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)
- [Propel](http://propelorm.org/)
- [PHP Activerecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)